# How to display/convert a string of utf-8 to the proper symbol

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a list that has WhatsApp emoticons encoded as utf-8 characters. The table I am using to decode the emoticons is at http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

With this table I am trying to count the number of emoticons used, which I have successfully done using regex techniques. The problem is I have created a dictionary where the keys are the utf-8 characters as strings and the key_values are integers. The following:

```
print d_emo
for k, v in d_emo.items():
    print k.encode('utf8'), v
```

produces this output:

```
{'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\xA2': 2, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x82': 1, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x86': 2, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x89': 1, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\xB5': 2, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\xB0': 4, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\xAB': 2, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\xA9': 2, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x98': 1, '\\xE2\\x98\\xBA': 33, '\\xE2\\x98\\x95': 1}
\xF0\x9F\x98\xA2 2
\xF0\x9F\x98\x82 1
\xF0\x9F\x98\x86 2
\xF0\x9F\x98\x89 1
\xF0\x9F\x8D\xB5 2
\xF0\x9F\x8D\xB0 4
\xF0\x9F\x8D\xAB 2
\xF0\x9F\x8D\xA9 2
\xF0\x9F\x98\x98 1
\xE2\x98\xBA 33
\xE2\x98\x95 1
```

If I use this code:

```
for k, v in d_emo.items():
    print k.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape'), v
```

I get

```
ð¢ 2
ð 1
ð 2
ð 1
ðµ 2
ð° 4
ð« 2
ð© 2
ð 1
âº 33
â 1
```

I should be getting smiley faces and the like. Any suggestions? This is in Python 2.7.

Comment: Are you using a font that has all the glyphs for the emoticons?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes it does. When I read in the original textfile using *.readlines() and print * it displays the proper emoticons

Comment: what is your input (show `print repr(your_input)`)? What is shown in your question is not utf-8 data.

Comment: You may also use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/emoji, e.g. `python -c "import emoji ; print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbsup:', use_aliases=True))"`

Answer (score 2):

This will decode the Unicode characters correctly, but in Python 2.X you are somewhat limited when using characters outside the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane, characters U+0000 to U+FFFF):

```
import unicodedata as ud
D = {'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\xA2': 2, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x82': 1, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x86': 2, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x89': 1, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\xB5': 2, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\xB0': 4, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\xAB': 2, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\xA9': 2, '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x98': 1, '\\xE2\\x98\\xBA': 33, '\\xE2\\x98\\x95': 1}
for k,v in D.iteritems():
    k = k.decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
    try:
        n = ud.name(k)
    except ValueError:
        n = 'no such name'
    print k,repr(k),n
```

Output:

```
☺ u'\u263a' WHITE SMILING FACE
 u'\U0001f369' no such name
☕ u'\u2615' HOT BEVERAGE
 u'\U0001f602' no such name
 u'\U0001f36b' no such name
 u'\U0001f622' no such name
 u'\U0001f609' no such name
 u'\U0001f618' no such name
 u'\U0001f606' no such name
 u'\U0001f375' no such name
 u'\U0001f370' no such name
```

It comes out better in Python 3.X:

```
import unicodedata as ud
D = {b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\xA2': 2, b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x82': 1, b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x86': 2, b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x89': 1, b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\xB5': 2, b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\xB0': 4, b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\xAB': 2, b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\xA9': 2, b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x98': 1, b'\\xE2\\x98\\xBA': 33, b'\\xE2\\x98\\x95': 1}
for k,v in D.items():
    k = k.decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
    try:
        n = ud.name(k)
    except ValueError:
        n = 'no such name'
    print(k,ascii(k),n)
```

Output (note your font has to support the characters):

```
 '\U0001f618' FACE THROWING A KISS
 '\U0001f370' SHORTCAKE
 '\U0001f622' CRYING FACE
 '\U0001f36b' CHOCOLATE BAR
 '\U0001f375' TEACUP WITHOUT HANDLE
 '\U0001f369' DOUGHNUT
 '\U0001f602' FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY
 '\U0001f609' WINKING FACE
☕ '\u2615' HOT BEVERAGE
 '\U0001f606' SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND TIGHTLY-CLOSED EYES
☺ '\u263a' WHITE SMILING FACE
```

Comment: it is wrong. Both Python 2 and 3 can print non-bmp characters e.g.:  `print(u'\U0001f606')` ().

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, where did I say it can't?  The 2.X example is printing them, but isn't naming them.

Comment: It is wrong because OP should fix whatever piece of software that produces `b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\xA2'` instead of `u'\U0001f622'`. It is inappropriate to even mention BMP in this context -- OP doesn't understand the difference between bytes, Unicode codepoints and their representations in Python source code.  I would understand if you said that Python X.Y uses Unicode Z version and therefore such and such characters (in particular, some emoticons) are not known to `unicodedata` yet but you can work with them anyway.