# Find emojis in a text using python

Tags: python, emoji

Hello I am trying to find all emojis in downloaded tweets using python 2.7

I've tried that using the following code:

```
import os
import codecs
import emoji
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def extract_emojis(token):
    emoji_list = []
    if token in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI:
        emoji_list.append(token)
    return emoji_list

for tweet in os.listdir(tweets_path):
    with codecs.open(tweets_path+tweet, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input_file:
        line = input_file.readline()
        while line:
            line = word_tokenize(line)
            for token in line:
                print extract_emojis(token)

            line = input_file.readline()
```

However I only get empty lists, instead of the emojis.  If I get the following tweet

```
schuld van de sossen  SP.a: wij hebben niks gedaan  Groen: we gaan energie VERBIEDEN!
```

the output of the code is

```
[]
```

instead of the desired output:

```
[, ]
```

Any help??
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your text it's decoded on utf-8  `text.decode('utf-8')`

Locate all emoji from your text, you must separate the text character by character `[str for str in decode]`

Saves all emoji in a list `[c for c in allchars if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI]`

Something like this:

```
import emoji
text     = "  lorum ipsum  de "
decode   = text.decode('utf-8')
allchars = [str for str in decode]
list     = [c for c in allchars if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI]
print list
```

> [u'\U0001f914', u'\U0001f648', u'\U0001f60c', u'\U0001f495',
>   u'\U0001f46d', u'\U0001f459']

To get back your Emojis try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587359/how-to-display-convert-a-string-of-utf-8-to-the-proper-symbol)

Answer (score 1):

This works in python 2 -

```
x = "schuld van de sossen  SP.a: wij hebben niks gedaan  Groen: we gaan energie VERBIEDEN!"
[i for i in x.split() if unicode(i, "utf-8") in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI]

# OP
['\xf0\x9f\x98\xa1', '\xf0\x9f\x98\xb4']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways by which we can extract the emojis from a string in Python.

On of the prominent is by using the **emoji** library.

If you are processing a file then make sure that you are read the file with encoding **utf-8**(while saving **utf-8-sig** too)

Here will show how to list all the emoji present in the string along with the no. of emojis in the string and type of each emoji

> Code:

```
#import required libraries
import emoji
from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI

#getting all emojis as lists
all_emojis = list(UNICODE_EMOJI.keys())

#defining sentence
sentence = "schuld van de sossen  SP.a: wij hebben niks gedaan  Groen: we gaan energie VERBIEDEN!"

#getting Emoji Count
emoji_count = sum([sentence.count(emoj) for emoj in UNICODE_EMOJI])
#listing all Emojis
listed_emojis = ','.join(re.findall(f"[{''.join(all_emojis)}]", str(sentence)))
#listing all Emoji Types
emoji_types = ','.join([UNICODE_EMOJI[detect_emoji].upper()[1:-1] for detect_emoji in listed_emojis.split(',')])

#Displaying Sentence, Emoji Count, Emojis and Emoji Types
print(f"Sentence: {sentence}\nListed Emojis: {listed_emojis}\nCount: {emoji_count}\nEmoji Types: {emoji_types}")
```

> Output:

```
Sentence: schuld van de sossen  SP.a: wij hebben niks gedaan  Groen: we gaan energie VERBIEDEN!
Listed Emojis: ,
Count: 2
Emoji Types: POUTING_FACE,SLEEPING_FACE
```

I hope this will helpful.. If anyone have query please write here. I will try to fix.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import emoji

text = "Hello!  How are you doing today?  It’s a beautiful day, isn’t it?  Don’t forget to take a break and enjoy a cup of coffee ☕ or tea . Remember, you’re doing great!  Keep up the good work! "
emojis = [c for c in text if c in emoji.EMOJI_DATA]

print(emojis)
```

Output:

```
['', '', '', '☕', '', '', '']
```